# A script to show me an IP and ns[1,2].* on the same line

Tags: bash, for-loop, dig

I have all the IPs that I want to `dig +trace -x` in a file called 'ips'.

I want to only see the ns1 (and/or) ns2 records of the IP and and have the IP and the ns1 or ns2 record output on the same line, like so:

```
1 - $IP - $NS
2 - $IP - $NS
etc.
```

Right now, I only have a script I call 'digdug', which looks like this...

```
for i in `cat ips`
do
dig +trace -x $i | tail -n7
done
```

and then I am able to see the IP that it is digging by running: `bash -x digdug`

But, what I really need is the IP and the ns record on one line, then the next IP in the list with ns record on the next line. Then the next and so on.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the output you'd like?  Say, for the ip 8.8.8.8, you want "1 - 8.8.8.8 - ns1.level3.net." and so forth?

Comment: Yeah, I would like it to read:

1 - $ip - $ns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
for ip in `cat ips`; do
  ns=`dig +trace -x $ip | tail -n7 | awk '/NS/ {print $NF}'`
  echo "$ip - $ns" | tr '\n' ' '
  echo ""
done
```

Comment: This solution works great, but it repeats all the output on one line instead of the output on separate lines. It needs to be a different IP on each line, descending.

Comment: Ah, of course. You need to print a newline after each line. Fixed.

Comment: Actually I meant to write `$NF`. Stupid habits ... :(

Answer (score 1):

another solution in bash 4 :

```
while read ip; do
    while read ns; do
       echo -e "$ip\t$ns";
    done < <(dig +trace -x $ip | grep -i "ns[12]")
done < ips
```

I prefer to use the `while TEST; do CMD; done < file` because it did not fork a subshell.

the `< <(cmd)` is for function substitution. Like the `<` redirection, bash do not create a subshell.

ex., here is a result on google IP (173.164.67.9[1-5]):

```
173.194.67.91   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS1.GOOGLE.COM.
173.194.67.91   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS2.GOOGLE.COM.
173.194.67.92   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS2.GOOGLE.COM.
173.194.67.92   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS1.GOOGLE.COM.
173.194.67.92   67.194.173.in-addr.arpa. 60     IN      SOA     ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 1497777 21600 3600 1209600 10800
173.194.67.93   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS2.GOOGLE.COM.
173.194.67.93   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS1.GOOGLE.COM.
173.194.67.94   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS2.GOOGLE.COM.
173.194.67.94   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS1.GOOGLE.COM.
173.194.67.95   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS1.GOOGLE.COM.
173.194.67.95   194.173.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      NS      NS2.GOOGLE.COM.
```

hope this will help

Comment: kool :) just add me a reputation please ;)